# HighStock - The time displayed on UI is different from the server data

Tags: highcharts

It seems that there is an error in the demo of [Highstock Demos › Flags marking events](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-general)

The chart display data from **2013-06-02** to **2015-06-30**

[image: highstock]

However, the data fetched via AJAX (http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?) shows that the time range is [**2013-05-02**, **2015-05-30**]

Anybody know the reason?

Comment: This is correct, because in Date.UTC() months are calculated from 0 not 1. In other words 5 means June not May.

Comment: @SebastianBochan From 0 to 11* is what you meant right ?

Comment: Oh thanks, I do not know the month starts with 0